# Ruby, does it allow Cartesian product constructors?

Tags: ruby, constructor, cartesian-product

As the title states, does Ruby allow Cartesian product types? I can't find anything on it anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Does it allow? Yes. Does it implement it in standard library? Probably not, but wouldn't be difficult to implement

Comment: @Chubas: I think "wouldn't be difficult to implement" is a *gross* understatement. Before you can implement product types, you would first have to implement a type system, and despite the great work of the [Diamondback Ruby](http://WWW.CS.UMD.Edu/projects/PL/druby/) project, that's probably still a PhD-level multi-year research project.

Comment: Well, what does Trevor really want? (Apart, of course, from a proper lesson in the fact that types really aren't what he seems to think they are…)

Answer (score 3):

Ruby doesn't allow types *at all*, at least not in the sense that you seem to be using the word "type". Therefore, it obviously doesn't support product types, either.

Ruby is a so-called "dynamically typed" language (using the pragmatic, programmer-jargon definition of the word "type") or an untyped language (using the mathematical, type-theoretic definition), so talking about "product types" simply doesn't make sense at all.

Or, if you want to, you can see a dynamically typed language as a statically typed language with only a single type which is the sum type of all dynamic types.

However, you *can* obviously construct *values* that *would* have a product type if Ruby had types *at all*:

```
class Tuple
  include Enumerable; include Comparable

  class << self
    alias_method :[], :new

    def call(length)
      class_name = :"Tuple#{length}"
      return const_get class_name if const_defined? class_name
      const_set class_name, Class.new(self) {
        (@length = length).times do |i| define_method :"_#{i+1}" do @ary[i] end end
      }
    end
  end

  def to_s; "(#{@ary.join(', ')})" end
  def inspect; "#<#{self.class} (#{@ary.map(&:inspect).join(', ')})>" end
  def to_a; @ary.dup end
  def [](*args) @ary[*args] end
  def each(*args, &block) @ary.each(*args, &block) end

  def <=>(other)
    raise TypeError unless other.is_a? self.class
    raise TypeError unless each_with_index.all? {|el, i| other.instance_variable_get(:@ary)[i].instance_of?(el.class) }
    map.with_index {|el, i| el <=> other.instance_variable_get(:@ary)[i] }.find(0) {|cmp| !cmp.zero? }
  end

  def initialize(*args)
    raise ArgumentError unless args.length == self.class.instance_variable_get(:@length)
    (@ary = args).freeze
  end
end
```

This will give you a way to construct n-Tuples, which of course are special cases of product types. For example, this:

```
t3 = Tuple.(3)[1, :two, 'three']
```

will construct a triple with the tuple type `(Fixnum, Symbol, String)`, which is a special case of the product type `Fixnum × Symbol × String`. But there is no way to represent and/or *enforce* those types in Ruby.

If you want to look deeper into type systems for Ruby, the [Diamondback Ruby](http://WWW.CS.UMD.Edu/projects/PL/druby/) project is a good starting point. It includes *tuple types*, for example, which are an instance of product types.